# Docker sudo permissions

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, ubuntu-22.04

I am able to run docker without sudo  but after sometimes it again  asks for  permissions and I am not able to Attach container in  VS code

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

Answer (score 2):

To sort out permission errors and to run containers, check the following command

```
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```